# Работа с Thread.Sleep();

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Подскажите, как работает метод `Thread.Sleep();` в таком кусочке кода, к примеру

```
listBox1.Items.Add("First Item");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
listBox1.Items.Add("Second Item");
```

Получается так, что когда выполняется этот кусок кода, сначало идет задержка, а потом сразу же добавляются 2 объекта в `listbox`. Но нужно, что бы сперва добавился первый объект, прошло 5 секунд и только потом второй. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то приведенный код *работает* именно так, как вы и написали: сначала добавляется первая запись, потом делается задержка потока, потом добавляется вторая запись. А вот *видите* вы другой результат: сначала задержка, потом добавление двух записей. Это происходит из-за того, что задержку вы делаете в главном, UI, потоке. У UI потока есть т.н. очередь сообщений, которую он обрабатывает. После добавления первой записи в эту очередь добавляется сообщение о том, что нужно нарисовать текст в контроле. Но поскольку вы тут же делаете задержку, обработка этой очереди останавливается и поток просто не успевает *нарисовать* первую запись в контроле. После того, как задержка заканчивается, в очередь добавляется еще одно сообщение, и поток отрисовывает обе записи.

Сложно посоветовать, как это исправить, поскольку непонятно, чего вы хотите добиться. К тому же делать задержки (особенно в UI потоке) -- как правило плохая идея. Как вариант -- можно попросить UI поток обработать очередь сообщений перед задержкой:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("First Item");
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
listBox1.Items.Add("Second Item");
```

Но, повторюсь, это только в порядке удовлетворения любопытства. По-хорошему от задержки надо избавляться и делать то, что вы хотите, по-другому. Например, использовать [таймер](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) или [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Вообще, на мой вопросы Вы ответили. Спасибо, работает. Но тут вылез подводный камень. По сути я просто хочу сымитировать небольшую задержку в приложении. и перед добавлением 1ого элемента в листбокс, я запускаю таймер, в котором выводится простое сообщение, аля "подождите пару секунд", так вот он то ли запускается только после того, как приложение поспит 5 секунд, толи он запускается, но "тикнуть" не успевает. Буду признателен если по этому подводному камню тоже оставите пояснения.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков оформите это отдельным вопросом и добавьте в него код, достаточный для воспроизведения.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560312/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B2-c