# Работа с многопоточностью в c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    listBox1.Items.Add("First Item");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000;i++ )
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value += 1;
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    listBox1.Items.Add("Second Item");
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Please, wait...";
    //через некоторое время таймер остановится, код опустил
}
```

По сути я просто хочу сымитировать небольшую задержку в приложении. и перед добавлением 1ого элемента в листбокс, я запускаю таймер, в котором выводится простое сообщение, аля "подождите пару секунд", так вот он то ли запускается только после того, как приложение поспит 5 секунд, толи он запускается, но "тикнуть" не успевает.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите добавить первую запись, вывести "Please, wait", подождать пять секунд и добавить вторую запись?

Comment: Именно, ну еще пока эти самые 5 секунд идут работал прогрессбар, т.е. в соответсвии с тиками таймера постепенно увеличивался. По сути просто имитирую задержку, мол приложение работает с большими данными.

Comment: Так как ответ уже дали, запомните, что Thread.Sleep(); отправляет в сон поток с вашим приложением, и к созданному вами таймеру отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала стоит внимательно почитать, как работает таймер, потому что сейчас, судя по коду, у вас нет этого понимания.

Код, который должен выводить "Please wait" до запуска таймера, у вас почему-то в `timer1_Tick()`, а код, которые должен быть в тике, расположен в `button1_Click()`. Задержка же вообще не нужна, поскольку у вас уже есть таймер!

Схема должна быть следующая:

- добавляем первую запись
- выводим "Please wait"
- запускаем таймер
- в каждом тике увеличиваем значение прогресс бара
- как только закончили считать, останавливаем таймер, добавляем вторую запись и убираем "Please wait"

Должно быть примерно так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("First Item");
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Please, wait...";
    progressBar1.Value = 0;

    // за 5 секунд тикнет 100 раз, этого достаточно, можно даже и реже
    timer1.Interval = 50;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value++;

    // подразумевается, что максимум равен 100
    // в любом случае интервал таймера * максимум прогресс бара
    // должен давать желаемую задержку в мс
    if (toolStripProgressBar1.Value == 100)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = string.Empty;
        listBox1.Items.Add("Second Item");
    }
}
```

Как вариант, можно иметь два таймера, чтобы избавиться от неочевидной зависимости "интервал таймера * максимум прогресс бара
== задержка в мс". Первый таймер тикает раз в 100 мс и увеличивает прогресс бар. Второй таймер срабатывает через 5 секунд, останавливает оба таймера и добавляет/обновляет записи.

Comment: Вот как логика построение приложения откидывает лишние вопросы, благодарю!

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков логика откидывает все, кроме велений сердца :). Не за что!